# Linking together different columns in a SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I'm not very experienced with advance SQL queries, I'm familiar with basic statements and basic joins, currently trying to figure out how to write a query that seems to be out of my depth and I haven't been able to find a solution from google so far and I'm hoping somebody might be able to point me in the right direction.

The table I'm working with has an ID column, and a 'parent id' column.

I'm looking for all descendants of ID '1' - rows with a parent ID of '1', rows with a parent ID equal to any row's ID with a parent ID of '1' etc. Currently I've been doing this manually but there are hundreds of descendants so far and I feel like there's a way to put this into one query.

Any help would be appreciated, if this is unclear I can also try to clarify.

EDIT -  I got it working with the following query:

```
with cteMappings as (
select map_id, parent_map_id, map_name
     from admin_map
     where map_id = '1'
union all
select a.map_id, a.parent_map_id, a.map_name
     from admin_map a
         inner join cteMappings m
             on a.parent_map_id = m.map_id
)
select map_id, parent_map_id, map_name
    from cteMappings
```

Comment: What database are you using?  What you are looking for is a recursive query (usually implemented with a recursive CTE), but not all databases support this functionality.

Comment: It's a SQL database. I'm not sure if this is the answer you're looking for. Using SQL Server Management Studio. Please let me know if I can clarify further.

Comment: Corey: **SQL** is just the **query language** - not a database product. What you're using is (Microsoft) **SQL Server** - use the `sql-server` tag to indicate this! (I added this for you already)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it can be achieved by Common Table Expression:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1, 1), parent_id INT);
INSERT @temp
    SELECT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL

SELECT * FROM @temp

; WITH HierarchyTemp (id, parent_id, depth) AS (
    SELECT id, parent_id, 0
    FROM @temp
    WHERE id = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, ht.depth + 1
    FROM @temp t
        INNER JOIN HierarchyTemp ht ON ht.id = t.parent_id
)

SELECT * 
FROM HierarchyTemp
```

So the above example is creating a table variable with 4 rows:

```
id parent_id
1  NULL
2  1
3  2
4  NULL
```

Result of descendent of id '1' (also including itself, but can be excluded with an additional WHERE clause):

```
id parent_id depth
1  NULL      0
2  1         1
3  2         2
```